Where is the implementation of an annotation's effects/behavior?
As per my understanding, an annotation is metadata. which will do its job either at compile time or runtime.
Consider the annotation @Override, which ensure that a method is defined in super-class/interface and I am overriding it. If not, the compiler throws an error. My question is, where is the actual business logic written about this check? Here I assume, it should be written in javac compiler as this annotation is part of java.base module.
But what about the annotation like @PostConstruct (from javax.annotation) & @Getter (from Lombok). Those are the annotation added as a JAR dependency. I am searching the implementation of it, but did not find it. Like how is the @PostConstruct logic invoked? How is @Getter invoked and create getter method of the field and embed it into the .class file?
In other words, where can I find the under the hood mechanism which drives the behavior of annotation?

That's what, so called, annotation processors do. See GetterHandler, for example.

@Override is part of the language and is implemented in the compiler.  I'm pretty sure that Lombok uses Annotation Processors and gets implemented at compile time and by an external resource that extends javac.  Other annotations might be implemented at run time, such as during class loading using reflection or bytecode weaving.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

There is no single under the hood mechanism that drives the behavior of annotations.

Some compile time annotations are implemented by the compiler itself.  As of Java 21, these are @Target, @Retention, @Inherited, @Override, @SuppressWarnings, @Deprecated, @SafeVarargs, @Repeatable, and @FunctionalInterface
Other compile time annotations are handled by custom annotation processors.
Some annotations are handled in a "bytecode-weaving" step between bytecode compilation and runtime.  This typically entails some tool reading the class files, and modifying their bytecodes.
Some annotations are handled at runtime, either during class loading, using the instrumentation APIs or by other means.  For example, user or library code can user reflection to retrieve runtime annotations for a class, and modify application behavior in some way depending on what it finds.

Also, some annotations don't actually have a behavioral effect.  For example, some are used to drive static code analyzers whose purpose is to identify bugs in the application before they happen.  For example, if a method parameter is declared as @NotNull, a static analyzer may be able to identify places where the method is called with a potentially null argument.
So ... where is the code to implement the behavior?  It depends on the annotation.  For @Override it will be in the javac codebase, @PostConstruct - the Spring codebase, @Getter - the Lombok codebase, and so on.
See also:

Standard APIs for compile time annotation processors: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html
https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder
https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269


i am least concern about the compile time annotation like @Override & @FunctionalInterface as javac have instruction of it.
But what about @PostConstruct(is from javax.annotation, not spring) and @Getter. which are part of 3rd party jar and i did not find implementation of it into that jar.

The package that defines the annotation is immaterial.  What you need to find is the code that processes the annotation. There is no straightforward way to do this.  I am inferring that since @PostConstruct is used in Spring's DI framework at runtime, that framework must know how to process that annotation.  Likewise, something in the Lombok codebase must know how to handle @Getter ...

@RBS Some annotations may even be processed by several different frameworks - for example PostConstruct is handled by Eclipse RCP as well as Spring, using different code

Based on above comments, is it right to say, Annotation is just a contract(Annotation also defined with @Interface) and we need to provide implementation of it while we compile our code in which those annotation is declared. so when we are done with compilation, the resultant .class file contains linking of implementation of annotation interface and at the runtime that implementation calls.

@RBS No, for things like PostConstruct nothing is decided until the code is run. The framework that supports PostConstruct uses reflection to get the methods in a class and uses java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation to find a method which has the PostConstruct annotation. In Eclipse RCP, for example, that is not done until an instance of the class is created using the injection mechanism.
